# jQuery Repetitive Multi-Color Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Using jQuery, how can I gradually change from a first color, to a second color, to a third color, and then back repeating all within a master animation?

**Purpose:** I am attempting to create a progress bar which oscillates through colors.

Current Code

```
$('div').animation({width:'100%'}, ***varying time frame***, 'linear');
```

Comment: Color animations require a special plugin : https://jqueryui.com/animate/. The other option would be to write your own animation based on `rbg` or `hsl` (either of those seem easiest). Unless your `.animation()` method has some magical properties of course. :-D

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
var colors = ["Red","Green","Blue","Black"];
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    $("#pb").animate({
        backgroundColor:colors[i]
    },800);
    if(i > colors.length-1){
        i = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
},1500);

setInterval(function(){
    var width = $("#pb").width();
        if(width < 300){
         $("#pb").animate({
            width:"+=25"
        },300);
    }
},700);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/edLqkyre/)**